# sourceMap in Webpack - devtool vs loaders

Tags: webpack, webpack-style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader, postcss-loader

Webpack 3.

What is the relations between [Webpack's Devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/#devtool) and the sourceMap attribute in [sass-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader#source-maps), [postcss-loader](https://github.com/postcss/postcss-loader#sourcemap), [css-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader#sourcemap) and [style-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/style-loader#sourcemap).
Overriding? Overlapping?

Its seems to me devtool is not effecting the sourceMaps while loaders are defined.

Will be happy to hear your findings.